# Edit main controller's value in apex:component's controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I have a component:

```
<apex:component controller="Demo_CTRL" allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="isVisible" assignTo="{!flag}" type="Boolean" description="Boolean description"/>
// some more code goes here
<apex:commandButton action="{!done}" reRender="stuff" status="loading"/>
</apex:component>

class Demo_CTRL {
    public Boolean flag {get;set;}
    public Void done() {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

I'm calling my component from my VF page in the following manner:

```
<c:demoComp isVisible="{!flag}"/>
```

I want to manipulate the `flag` variable in my component's controller so that it reflects in the VF page controller but I haven't been able to do so.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use component’s setter to manipulate the property.

Comment: @RahulSharma can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @d_k, If I understood correctly, do you want to access the updated value of the `flag` manipulated by `done` method of Component inside your VF page's controller?

Comment: @MadhaviBhattad I want the value of flag (which is in VF page controller) to be updated from apex:component's controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass the value back to the parent controller, you should instantiate the controller from the parent and pass it in.

```
<apex:attribute name="controller" type="Demo_CTRL" required="true"
    "Controller which sets flag and performs action" />
```

Now if you manipulate state in this controller instance, your parent page should be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I worry that this will affect the view state of my page

Comment: @d_k It will affect the view state of your page... by approximately four bytes. I don't think you'll miss it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @adrian larson's answer:

```
<apex:component controller="Demo_CTRL" allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="currentState" assignTo="{!state}" type="CurrentState" description="description"/>
// some more code goes here
<apex:commandButton action="{!done}" reRender="stuff" status="loading"/>
</apex:component>

class Demo_CTRL {
   public CurrentState state {get;set;}
    public Void done() {
        state.flag = false;
    }
}

// this class object will be passed from the VF page
    class CurrentState {
       public Boolean flag{get;set;}
       //some other variables that are passed to the component
    }

<c:demoComp currentState="{!state}"/>
```

This worked just fine for me. Thanks!